# Python XML is not a package error

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to get the values from the XML file, using python 3.4, but I am getting an error while compiling the file. The error saying

```
ImportError: No module named 'xml.etree'; 'xml' is not a package
```

I have also tried to install the lxml package, but it is already existing, then I don't know why I am getting this error.

Can someone, please help me with this.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add the complete code to your question? Otherwise it is hard to guess what's the problem.

Comment: Try `import lxml.etree` instead of 'xml.etree'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, actually It worked after changing the file name. I believe there was a conflict with the file name while compiling. So, after changing the file name it worked. Thanks for all your time.

Comment: Which file name?

Comment: I actually had my file name as xml.py, which I was trying to compile, so there was an error saying xml is not a package. I then changed the file name to something like events and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Do not save your file as `xml.py`, instead use a different file name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your late answer to an old and already answered question is basically a duplicate of [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50283295/5698098). – As your answer is more concise it's probably OK; however duplicating existing answers on old questions is not OK in general (see [How to handle cleanup of late blatantly duplicate answers ('surfing') on popular questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385063/5698098)).– And as you're starting out here, also have look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for further hints.